# PHP Mysql Jquery - Dynamic table preloaded with tab and a Add more button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to create a dynamic table with 4 columns. 1 column automatically pulls the values from a query and preloads each row with the data. The second column is a dynamic select menu that pulls data from another query and the other 2 columns are simple input fields. There's also an add more button and a remove button.

I was able to create the dynamic select menu but i can't preload the current model rows with the each query values. Currently, my code adds all values to each line. For example, the code below creates the following:

```
 Current Serial | Current Model    | Department | IP
  *Select Menu* | Model A, Model B |            |
  *Select Menu* | Model A, Model B |            |
```

The desired output should be

```
 Current Serial | Current Model    | Department | IP
  *Select Menu* | Model A          |            |
  *Select Menu* | Model B          |            |
```

Here's the Jquery:

```
**Count how many rows shows be in the table**
 var num = <?php echo $row_cnt; ?>;

**Turn the number of rows into an array**
 var arr = [];
 for (var i=1; i <= num; i++) {
 arr.push(i);
 }

 **For each value of the row_count, create a row**
 jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {

 var html = '';
 html += '<tr>';


 html += '<td><input list="current_serials" id="current_serial[]" name="current_serial[]" placeholder="Current Serial" class="equipment_current_serial form-control item_current_serial" autocomplete="off" ><datalist id="current_serials"><option value=""></option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box_current_serial($connect); ?></datalist></td>';

 html += '<td><input id="current_machine[]" name="current_machine[]" placeholder="Current Model" class="form-control" value="<?php echo fill_unit_select_box_current_machine($connect); ?>"   ></td>';


 html += '<td><input type="text" class="equipment_dept form-control" placeholder="Dept" id="dept[]" name="dept[]" id="dept[]" ></td>';

 html += '<td><input type="text" class="equipment_ipaddress form-control" placeholder="IP Address" id="ipaddress[]" name="ipaddress[]" id="ipaddress[]" ></td>';

 html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';




 **Append to the table**
 $('#item_table').append(html);
 });
```

Now the PHP functions to fill the table

```
 **This function works fine**
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=", "", "");
 function fill_unit_select_box_current_serial($connect)
 { 

 $output = '';
  $query = '';
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
   $output .= '<option value="'.$row["nextgenorder_serial"].'">'.$row["data"].'</option>';
  }
  return $output;
 }
```

This is the problem

```
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=", "", "");
 function fill_unit_select_box_current_machine($connect)
 { 

 $output = '';
  $query = '';
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
    $output = $row["nextgenorder_itemdescription"];
  }
  return $output;
 }
```

Can you please assist to get the desired output?

Thanks,

Comment: whatever query that function is executing (which would be really helpful to see), it would appear that it is returning whatever the last row in the result was, which doesn't make much sense. But without the queries, or any look at what the data in the database looks like or even what the raw query results were, there's not much more to say. The most important information is missing.